# Does the FBLoginView return the correct id in the user object?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I know that Facebook has decided to encrypt app specific user id and the accepted way to acquire the current users id is to query the graph for /me. However, I noticed that my FBLoginView delegate method

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user;
```

returns a FBGraphUser which when accessing

```
[user objectForKey: @"id"]
```

returns my actual facebook id. Will this behavior change once all the calls are upgraded, or can I count on this object providing the correct facebook id?

Comment: User ids for users that logged into an app at least once using API v1 already will not change, your app will still receive the global user id for those; only for users that login using v2 for the first time, an app-scoped user id will be issued.

Comment: Ah, so it only seems like I am getting correct info now because I have probably logged into my app one the v1 api.

Comment: Yes. (But an app-scoped user id for a user that logged in for the first time only after v2 was used _is_ the “correct” info.)

Comment: I see. I guess I wanted the /me id because I filter some items based off the /me/friends call. Now I am curious though, if I call the /me/friends, will the user ids that appear be the app specific ones?

Comment: That depends on when those friends logged in to the app for the first time. (Please tell me you are aware that with API v2 your app will only be able to get friends that are users of the app as well …?)

Comment: The app-scoped user id _is_ “the /me id”, as you put it, btw. It is the only id your app is _supposed_ to see when dealing with users that logged in via v2 for the first time. Your app can not use the global user id for such users any more, that will just result in an error.

Comment: Yup I am aware, I already have the friend part set up (it only returns a fraction of my actual friend's list so I presume its working as intended). So I can count on the user id in the /me/friends call being the same as that in the FBLoginView delegate then?

Comment: Yes, of course. That is the only id by which your app will “know” the user.

Comment: Alright that actually makes a lot more sense now. I was struggling with the API last night because of all the changes but this seems a lot more convenient than whatever I thought it was. You can add a former answer to this question, otherwise I will. Thank you so much, you were really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User ids for users that logged into an app at least once using API v1 already will not change, your app will still receive the global user id for those; only for users that login using v2 for the first time (that is, have not used it before already), an app-scoped user id will be issued.

An app-scoped user id for a user that logged in for the first time only after v2 was used *is* the “correct” info. It is the only id your app is supposed to see when dealing with users that logged in via v2 for the first time. Your app can not use the global user id for such users any more, that will just result in an error.

**Edit:**
If a user used your app under v1 already, then you will still get their global user id, even if they removed the app from their settings and start using it again later on. (For example external websites that offer login via Facebook *need* that kind of consistency of course, so Facebook implemented it that way.)

Comment: One more question, if I or any user removes the app from facebook settings and relogs does that affect this at all?